# Does {% load staticfiles %} also work in css file in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I bought bootstrap theme and there is `.css` file something like this :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.eot");
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/fontello/fontello-.eot#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("../../assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.woff") format('woff'), url("../../assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.ttf") format('truetype'), url("../../assets/fonts/fontello/fontello.svg#fontello") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But I want to use `Django static template` so I changed it like below :

```
{% load staticfiles %}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url("{% static 'fonts/fontello/fontello.eot' %}");
  src: url("{% static 'fonts/fontello/fontello-.eot#iefix' %}") format('embedded-opentype'), url("{% static 'fonts/fontello/fontello.woff' %}") format('woff'), url("{% static 'fonts/fontello/fontello.ttf' %}") format('truetype'), url("{% static 'fonts/fontello/fontello.svg#fontello' %}") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But it doesn't work. `{% load staticfiles %}` only works in `html` file?

Then how can I deal with it in `css` file?

Comment: You cannot use template tags in static files. Either use a relative path, or the absolute path to your static directory - .e.g., `/static/fonts/font.eot`.

Comment: That might be the only way to deal with it.... thanks: )